# Mail Sending Error in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to  send mail using  code-igniter  email library

My send mail code is

```
          $config['useragent'] = 'CodeIgniter';        
          $config['mailpath']  = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';

          $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
          $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com';
          $config['smtp_port'] = 465;
          $config['smtp_user'] = 'kspardeshi8@gmail.com'; // my gmail account username
          $config['smtp_pass'] = 'XXXXX'; my gmail account password
           $this->load->library('email',$config);
          $this->email->from($this->input->post('mail'),$this->input->post('name'));
          $this->email->to('kspardeshi8@gmail.com'); 
          $this->email->subject('Property Enquiry Test');
          $this->email->message($this->input->post('comment')); 
   if ($this->email->send())
    {
      echo json_encode(array('info' => 'success', 'msg' => $this->email->print_debugger()));
     }
  else
  {
      echo json_encode(array('info' => 'error', 'msg' => $this->email->print_debugger()));
  }
```

I am using Linux server. I am getting below error.

**Unable to send email using PHP mail(). Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.**

From: "Kiran S Pardeshi"

Return-Path:

Reply-To: "kspardeshi8@gmail.com"

X-Sender: kspardeshi8@gmail.com

X-Mailer: CodeIgniter

X-Priority: 3 (Normal)

Message-ID: <553a082cc285a@gmail.com>

Mime-Version: 1.0

Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8

Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

Property Enquiry Test
Hi

Comment: Not sure whether codeigniter requires it, but have you installed a mail server?

Comment: If you are using xampp you will need to configure the mail settings in there I would also hide you email on here.

Answer (score 0):

Its a better practice to load your library in the constructor. Also add this code right after you declared all the configuration variables

> $this->email->initialize($config);

try it out.

Answer (score 0):

you need add your config

//for html type
$config['mailtype']='html';

//for html text
$config['mailtype']='text';

and also you should setting your gmail to enable <--i'm forget to tell about it

Hope this help you